# How do I check if input is an integer/string?

Tags: c++

My problem here is I don't know how to insert a rule wherein if a user inputted a number on the string, it will `cout` a warning saying it's not valid, same with if a user inputted a string/char on the grades. How? I've been trying it but the formula won't work.

```
int x, cstotal = 100, extotal = 150;

double scorecs, exscore, labtotala, labtotalb, total;

string mystr = "";

cout << "Compute for: " << "\n" << "1. Laboratory Grade " << "\n" << "2. Lecture Grade" << "\n" << "3. Exit" << "\n";
cout << "Please enter a number: ";
cin >> x;
switch (x) {
case 1:

    cout << "Compute for laboratory grade." << "\n";
    cout << "Enter Student Name: ";
    cin >> mystr;


    cout << "Good day, " << mystr << " . Please provide the following grades: " << "\n";
    cout << "CS Score: ";
    cin >> scorecs;

    cout << "Exam Score: ";
    cin >> exscore;


    labtotala = scorecs / cstotal * 0.6;
    labtotalb = exscore / extotal * 0.4;
    total = labtotala + labtotalb;
    cout << "Your Laboratory Grade is " << total * 100 << "\n";
    system("pause");
    break;
case 2:
    cout << "Compute for lecture grade." << "\n";
    cout << "Enter Student Name: ";
    cin >> mystr;
    cout << "Good day, " << mystr << " . Please provide the following grades: " << "\n";
    cout << "CS Score: ";
    cin >> scorecs;
    cout << "Exam Score: ";

    cin >> exscore;
    labtotala = scorecs / cstotal * 0.7;
    labtotalb = exscore / extotal * 0.3;
    total = labtotala + labtotalb;
    cout << "Your Lecture Grade is " << total * 100 << "\n";
    system("pause");
    break;
```

Comment: What part of the rule is giving you trouble?  How to implement the detection, control flow, branching?  If it's just a matter of detecting if a string is a number, you could loop through each character and call isdigit.

Comment: you need to be more specific as to what you are looking for. Post less code if possible.

Answer (score 14):

`cin` sets a [`failbit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/fail/) when it gets input of an invalid type.

```
int x;
cin >> x;

if (!cin) {
    // input was not an integer
}
```

You can also use `cin.fail()` to check if the input was valid:

```
if (cin.fail()) {
    // input was not valid
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this:

```
std::string str;
std::cin >> str;

if (std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::isdigit) != str.end())
{
    std::cout << "No digits allowed in name\n";
}
```

The above code loops through the whole string, calling [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) for each character. If the `std::isdigit` function returns true for any character, meaning it's a digit, then [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns an iterator to that place in the string where it was found. If no digits were found then the `end` iterator is returned. This way we can see if there was any digits in the string or not.

The C++11 standard also introduced new [algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) that can be used, but which basically does the above. The one that could be used instead is [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
if (std::any_of(str.begin(), str.end(), std::isdigit))
{
    std::cout << "No digits allowed in name\n";
}
```

Comment: So will this check whether or not an int is inside of the input? if so will you please explain your code?

Comment: @DylanLittle Updates my answer trying to explain what it does, and with links to references. Also added a "better" solution when using C++11 or later.

Comment: ahhh so much better. I can see what's going on now.

Answer (score 3):

```
    cout << "\n Enter number : ";
    cin >> ch;
    while (!cin) {
        cout << "\n ERROR, enter a number" ;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256,'\n');
        cin >> ch;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.fail()` method of the stream. Something like below:-

```
   cin >> aString;

  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << aString;
  int n;
  ss >> n;

  if (!ss.fail()) {
   // int;
  } else {
  // not int;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `cin.fail()` method! When `cin` fails it will be `true` and you could us a `while` loop to loop until the `cin` is `true`:

```
cin>>d;
while(cin.fail()) {
    cout << "Error: Enter an integer number!"<<endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(256,'\n');
    cin >> d;
}
```

Comment: It shold be just cin.ignore() in new compiler. cin.ignore(256,'\n') doesn’t work in updated compiler

Answer (score 0):

```
//this program really work in DEV c++
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    char input;
    cout<<"enter number or value to check"<<endl;
    cin>>input;
for(char i='a';i<='z';i++)
{
    if(input==i)
    {
        cout<<"character"<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++)
{
    if(input==i)
    {
        cout<<"number"<<endl;   
    }
}
}
```